# WMS of mixed cache from ArcGIS 10.2 not showing correctly in QGIS 2.14.9(Essen)

Tags: arcgis-10.2, wms, cache, qgis-2.14

I'm trying to publish a cache in ArcGIS 10.2 to WMS and to show it on QGIS, but something there doesn't work right, the WMS is displayed very partially (only specific layers and not others, sometimes only labels).

I created a mixed cache in ArcGIS 10.2. The cache consists of several vector layers showing different elements (streets, cities, park, rivers, buildings, viewshed etc.) in different scales. When I Publish it to a service I enable the WMS option, copy the soap URL and after publishing, I go to my QGIS 2.14.9(Essen) > Add WMS Layer > New > Paste the URL> connect > choose upmost 'Layers' and add to the map. The cache that is added is very partial, showing very few features of only part of the layers, sometimes only labels.

Am I doing something wrong? Am I skipping a step? Or are mixed-caches not supported in QGIS? I have a suspicion that the difference between the scales is causing the problem (that QGIS doesn't know how to handle the different scales - that some layers are shown only in specific scales and not in others) but I can't prove it.

EDIT: I tried to use the fiddler, but he didn't show me any sensible URL (when adding the WMS to QGIS).
This is the soap url I thought I should use[image: arcgis service window] and it actually works when I give the url of a cache of an orthophoto. Withe vector map cache it still doesn't...

Comment: When you say you use the ArcGIS SOAP URL as the WMS URL, are you certain that this is a WMS URL, I have a feeling that it isn't.

Comment: @nmtoken thanks, It still isn't working and I added the window I took the soap URL from.

Comment: So when you add `?service=WMS&request=GetCapabilities&` to that highlighted URL in a browser what result do you get?

Comment: @nmtoken, adding the **?service=WMS&request=GetCapabilities&**  to the highlighted URL solved the problem ( and I had to choose all layers when displaying the WMS) . It's a shame there isn't any official site stating this... thanks a million!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Or are mixed-caches not supported in QGIS?

QGIS supports WMS, so as long as your ArcGIS service is working correctly as a WMS then there should be no problem with QGIS accessing the data.

> I have a suspicion that the difference between the scales is causing
>   the problem (that QGIS doesn't know how to handle the different scales

A WMS doesn't deal with scales as such, the client (could be a browser, could be QGIS...)  sends a request to the server for a bounding box and an image size specified in pixel width and height, the server creates the image and sends it back.

> that some layers are shown only in specific scales and not in others)
>   but I can't prove it.

If you want to see whether QGIS is generating valid requests, or if ArcGIS WMS is responding correctly, you should try and capture the requests sent by QGIS to your ArcGIS WMS, then try them out in a browser.

hint: use Fiddler, and look at the the QGIS options for proxies